# Different LNG (methane) combinations with oxidizer

Tags: rockets, fuel, oxidizer

I was looking up oxidizers in two aspects, economy and power. Since much of math goes over my head, I got almost nothing.

What would be most economical  and most  powerful potent oxidizer choice available today? Is there a catalyst which can be helpful here?

Comment: **LNG** or [liquified natural gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquefied_natural_gas) refers to a mixture of liquified hydrocarbons, [usually only about 90% methane](http://www.liquefiedgascarrier.com/LNG.html) (CH4) and [usually >1% of butane](http://www.giignl.org/sites/default/files/PUBLIC_AREA/About_LNG/4_LNG_Basics/090801publique_lngbasics_lng_1_-_basic_properties_7.2.09_aacomments.pdf) (C4H10), with the balance as ethane and propane (C2H6, C3H8). Better to call it just liquid methane, or LCH4 perhaps, if you want to refer to the pure substance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oxygen is the best oxidiser that's also simple to handle and inexpensive. Better oxidisers exist, but they are expensive and can be toxic and/or corrosive, making them difficult to handle. In particular, fluorine can give very high specific impulse, but is nearly impossible to work with safely so it's never been used in production rockets.

Here's a [good list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_rocket_propellant#Lithium_and_fluorine) of propellants and oxidizers.

Comment: I imagine that dumping many tons of hydrogen fluoride into the air would not be popular either.

Comment: @MikeH Yikes! You know what they say about people who live in glass houses - *they shouldn't play with HF*.

Comment: HF is very corrosive to glass surfaces, but it is dangeously toxic for human skin.